# Multiple dropdown to change another value using ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 dropdowns and 1 label in html. I want to change the label value when user has changed 2 dropdowns using ajax. How can i change it?, is it possible without using any button in it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @JanPeter nope, i just think about it, is it possible?, without button and when user just select one dropdown, the value doesn't changing value of label.

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery documentation to see if what you want to do is possible? [hint](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: @user3505775 yes ist is possible.

Comment: @JanPeter i have tried but i still don't understand. Can you show me how to create 2 dropdown and change the label?